# Menu with Automatic Pages Included from Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

Question - How can one utilize the wordpress 3.0 Menu system to automatically have new pages from a custom post type included within the menu (I am referring to the Menu Management area of wordpress for the public website).

I believe this currently works for the regular "pages" if you check the automatically incude box but is there a way to also hard code it to work for pages from a custom post type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is accomplished by `_wp_auto_add_pages_to_menu()` (in `\wp-includes\nav-menu.php`) function that is hooked to `transition_post_status` hook.

Unfortunately it is hardcoded for `page` post type and is not easy to extend.

On other hand since it works through generic hook it isn't hard (relatively, menus internal code is pain) to engineer analogue for custom post type.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please take a moment and provide the code I would need to add which would allow me to achieve these goals?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any custom post types set up, so it would me extremely hard for me to write this piece of code theoretically, without being able to test<->refine in process.

Comment: If I send you a complete code to add to your functions.php file which essentially creates everything for you would you possibly be able to test it?

Comment: I suggest you update your question with whatever code you have. There are plenty of people around here who do work with custom posts.