# Adding class "current_page_item" for custom post type menu

Tags: custom-post-types

I am using the following to help display a list of posts created in a custom post type.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'=>'portfolio',
  'title_li'=> __('Portfolio')
);
wp_list_pages( $args );
```

However a class is not being added to the list item of the current page (`current_page_item`).  Any ideas of how I could make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this and it works perfectly!

[Dynamic navigation for custom post type (pages)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3247/dynamic-navigation-for-custom-post-type-pages/3270#3270)

Answer (score 3):

Check this ticket: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17590

Quickfix by husobj:

```
function my_page_css_class( $css_class, $page ) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->ID == $page->ID ) {
        $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
    }
    return $css_class;
}
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'my_page_css_class', 10, 2 );
```

The quickfix might be an easier alternative?
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to make the parent post type active in the menu:

```
<?php

add_action('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_current_nav_class', 10, 2 );

function add_current_nav_class($classes, $item) {

    // Getting the current post details
    global $post;

    // Getting the post type of the current post
    $current_post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type($post->ID));
    $current_post_type_slug = $current_post_type->rewrite[slug];

    // Getting the URL of the menu item
    $menu_slug = strtolower(trim($item->url));

    // If the menu item URL contains the current post types slug add the current-menu-item class
    if (strpos($menu_slug,$current_post_type_slug) !== false) {

       $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';

    }

    // Return the corrected set of classes to be added to the menu item
    return $classes;

}

?>
```

I found this code [in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/gerbenvandijk/5253921) and it worked for me - it marks the parent navigation as active when on a custom post type single post.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a workaround that worked in my situation.

I had Custom Post Type with Custom Taxonomy and wanted to list these posts as long as they were in a particular Custom Category - with current page class on the `li`.

The code above<sup>`*`</sup> produced a list of all posts, but didn't filter categories.
<sup>`*` [editor note] Answers may vary its order, not sure what code is being referred.</sup>

My solution comes from that code, not sure if it's best practice, but it works..

```
<?php
// get current page/post ID
$pageID = get_the_ID();
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'developments', 'custom_cat' => 'current' ) );
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : 
        the_post();
        // test if current page/post ID matches
        if ( $post->ID == $pageID ) {
            $class = 'current_page_item';
        } else {
            $class = '';
        }
?>
        <li <?php if ($class != '') echo 'class="'.$class.'"'; ?>>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
<?php 
    endwhile; 
endif; 
wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your functions.php:

```
function kct_page_css_class( $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) {
  if ( !isset($args['post_type']) || !is_singular($args['post_type']) )
    return $css_class;

  global $post;
  $current_page  = $post->ID;
  $_current_page = $post;
  _get_post_ancestors($_current_page);

  if ( isset($_current_page->ancestors) && in_array($page->ID, (array) $_current_page->ancestors) )
    $css_class[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
  if ( $page->ID == $current_page )
    $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
  elseif ( $_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent )
    $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';

  return $css_class;
}
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'kct_page_css_class', 10, 5 );
```

Via http://kucrut.org/wp_list_pages-for-custom-post-types/

Answer (score 0):

```
if(site_url()."/".get_post_type() == $menu_item->url || site_url()."/".$post->post_name == $menu_item->url){#STUFF TO IDENTIFY ON FRONT}
```

helps me adding currently active class to current menu item when I LOOP `wp_get_nav_menu_items` as  `foreach($primary_nav_menu_items as $n => $menu_item){#do something}` . It may help someone.