# Adding 'current_post_item' class to current post in the loop

Tags: loop, sidebar

I'm using a loop in the sidebar of my site to show all the posts that are in that category.
Now I'd like to include a 'current_post' class to the current post that is being displayed to style that item in the list.

I've tried looking for conditional tags or this custom [wp_list_post_types function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6333/adding-class-current-page-item-for-custom-post-type-menu) but both haven't worked.
Does anybody know if there's a way to do this?

EDIT: Adding Loop from comment below

```
<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
$postcat= $category->cat_ID; 
$catname =$category->cat_name; } 
$args = array( 'cat' => $postcat ); 
$my_query = new WP_Query(); 
$my_query->query($args); // Equivalent of query_posts()

while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
$id=get_the_ID();   
$currentClass= ($post->ID == $id) ? "current_post": ""; ?>
<a class="<?php echo   $currentClass; ?>" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">ni</a> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to get the queried object id and use that for comparison inside your custom loop..

Before your existing loop code(what you have posted above), but obviously after the opening PHP tag..

```
global $wp_query;
$current_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
```

Then somewhere inside your custom WP loops..

```
if( $current_id == get_the_ID() ) {
    // This result is the current one
}
else {
    // Not current
}
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: Yeah, that worked!

Comment: Brilliant - this has helped me out! Awesome stuff! @t31os

Comment: Great solution; thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a loop you should be able to do something like this it is untested but should work. Loop for sidebar

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
<?php while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
<?php while( have_posts() ){ 
 $id=get_the_ID();
 $currentClass= ($post->ID == $id) ? "current_post": ""; ?>
```

Then
`<div class="post <?php echo $currentClass; ?>">.....`

This isn't tested so I'm sort of just assuming that `$post->ID` will get the ID of the post outside and `get_the_ID()` will get the ID of the post inside the loop. If that doesn't work could you post your loop code and I'll do some test

**EDIT**

There is a few problems with your loop. One is that it's only grabbing the last category. I did a quick google search and found a soultion that seems to work on my test install [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-display-post-titles-from-current-category-and-highlight-active-post?replies=15#post-1055759)

This will only show if they are on a Single post page. Otherwise bad things happen (IE duplicate post showing etc)

```
    <ul>
<?php
$IDOutsideLoop = $post->ID;
while( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
if(is_single()){
    foreach( ( get_the_category() ) as $category )
        $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=' . $category->category_nicename . '&orderby=title&order=asc&showposts=100');
    if( $my_query ) {
        while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            $my_query->the_post(); 
                        $currentClass=( is_single() && $IDOutsideLoop == $post->ID ) ? ' class="current_post"' : '';                    ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" <?php echo $currentClass ?>><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
<?php
        }
    }
}
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work... :S Here's the loop I'm using:

`<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
  $postcat= $category->cat_ID; 
  $catname =$category->cat_name;
  }
  $args = array( 'cat' => $postcat );
  $my_query = new WP_Query();
  $my_query->query($args); // Equivalent of query_posts()
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
  $id=get_the_ID();
   $currentClass= ($post->ID == $id) ? "current_post": ""; ?>
  <a class="<?php echo $currentClass; ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">ni</a>
 <?php endwhile; ?>`

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting of the code, just getting the hang of mini-markdown! :)

Comment: @squrler, it's generally conceded better practice to edit original question with the code. This provides better formatting. I did this for you. However, it must be approved first.