# How do I add a current class to the current post?

Tags: filters

I have this list set up of the latest 7 posts:

```
            <ul id="post-list">
            <?php
            global $post;
            $args = array( 'numberposts' => 7 );
            $myposts = get_posts( $args );
            foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><br /><span><?php the_author(); ?></span></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
```

How can I have a class of 'current' be displayed for the current post?

Comment: Does the solution in [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14531/adding-current-post-item-class-to-current-post-in-the-loop) work?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<ul id="post-list">
    <?php
        global $post,$wp_query;
    $current_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 7 );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <li<?php if ($current_id == $post->ID) echo ' class="current"'; ?>>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><br /><span><?php the_author(); ?></span></a>
                </li>   
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```