# Current class hook on generated list

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I want to style a current state with CSS to indicate the page currently being viewed, but [List category posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/) doesn't generate a class hook. All it would need is something similar to the [solution posted here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26841/how-do-i-add-a-current-class-to-the-current-post).

How or where would I modify the plugin or request that the feature to be added?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I'm using eStore 2.9 with a combination of List-Category-Posts and Dynamic Widgets. They all work as expected, but neither List-Category-Posts nor any similar plugin allows me to list posts in a category AND generate a .current class for me to style with. So I'm left with trying to hack (possibly) the plugin to give me current class hook.

And no it's not a homebrewed sidebar. I'd rather the >Menu option in the CP worked its magic.

To recap what I want to achieve: the list-category-post plugin generates a list of links for a given category, like so:

```
<h4>Category Name</h4>
<ul>
<li><a>Apples</a></li>
<li><a>Oranges</a></li>
<li><a>Pears</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want a .current class attached to either the li or a tag of the currently viewed page in the said list:

```
<h4>Category Name</h4>
<ul>
<li class="current"><a>Apples</a></li>
<li><a>Oranges</a></li>
<li><a>Pears</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What wordpress function are you using to generate your navigation list or is it home-brewed?

Comment: Also, wich theme are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Fernando, the plugin's developer, has graciously added the feature to a new version of the plugin. I'm impressed and very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to style, but if you can edit your theme, you can add classes to the body tag which will indicate which page/post/category is being viewed. Look in the header.php file and make sure the body tag looks like this:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Here's the full reference:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class#Examples

Best of luck, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. And yes I already have that in the body. But it there isn't a corresponding .current class on the category post link there's little that I can do.