# Active class to current link

Tags: menus, links

How do I add the active class to the current link that the user is viewing? I have a mixture of pages and custom post types in my main nav menu and I know that wordpress has `.current_page_item` that can be used but when I tried that nothing happened. 
I'm slightly confused about how to implement it. Currently the menus for the site are being pulled in using:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
```

AND:

`<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Mobile Menu' )); ?>` - for mobile state.

Comment: hi may b u should take a look at this might be wat ur looking for...http://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-active-class-to-active-menu-item

Comment: thanks that worked for pages but when I click on the custom post types in the nav menu it doesnt work.

Comment: hi check this post ur done i believe..if not reply back..http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6333/adding-class-current-page-item-for-custom-post-type-menu

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

Two things:

1. `wp_nav_menu()` also outputs `.current_page_item`, as backward compatibility with `wp_page_menu()`.
2. Among [the list item CSS classes added by `wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes), for a custom post type, list items will have a CSS class `.list-type-object-{slug}`, where `{slug}` is the CPT slug. So, you could target: `.list-type-object-{slug}.current-list-item`

### Original Answer

The key is in the class name: `.current_page_item`. That [class is added by `wp_page_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu#Current-Page_Menu_Items), whereas [`wp_nav_menu()` adds `.current-list-item`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Current-Page_Menu_Items).

What that means is that `wp_nav_menu()` is outputting its *fallback* menu, and not a user-created custom nav menu.

Ensure:

1. Custom nav menu Theme Location is registered via `register_nav_menu()` or `register_nav_menus()`
2. Call to `wp_nav_menu()` includes the `theme_location` parameter *and not the `menu` parameter`, and that the`theme_location`passed to`wp_nav_menu()`matches the one defined in`register_nav_menu()`/`register_nav_menus()`
3. At least one custom nav menu is defined via `Appearance -> Menus`
4. A defined custom nav menu is assigned to the Theme Location that corresponds to `theme_location` passed to `wp_nav_menu()`.

For example:

1. Register

   ```
   function wpse117502_theme_setup() {
       register_nav_menus( array(
           'primary' => 'Primary'
       ) );
   }
   add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse117502_theme_setup' );
   ```
2. Call

   ```
   wp_nav_menu( array(
       'theme_location' => 'primary'
   ) );
   ```
3. Define

   User creates a menu, e.g. "Main Menu"
4. Assign

   User assigns "Main Menu" to **"Primary"** Theme Location

Comment: Thanks @chip Ive realised that for the page items in my navigation the class being applied by wordpress is: `li.current-menu-item` and so I can style those ones as I please, however for the custom post types I cant figure out which class wordpress is assigning which is making it difficult to style them.

Comment: Did you check the [linked Codex references for `wp_nav_menu()` list item classes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes)? (See edited answer.)

Comment: I have read through the codex but everything I try for the custom post types isnt working. The custom post types are in the main nav and then they are sub-nav items. I have viewed the source code and found that wordpress is assigning the following class to the current post type page:                            `menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-133 current_page_item menu-item-137`

Comment: Nope; you're on a static page: `menu-item-object-page`. Can you post a live link?

Comment: http://www.purpleclaw.org.uk/lulu/ - Link to the site

Comment: Yep; that is *definitely* a static page. It is custom page template `template-recent-work.php`.

Comment: You are quite right recent work is a static page. However music, commercial, promo etc are post types but they are using template files is this wrong? For the custom post types should I be using single-CPT.php instead of template-CPT.php

Comment: If you're displaying your CPTs via custom page template, then the object will always be a *page*, and not your post type. You could display either `single-{posttype}.php` or `archive-{posttype}.php` in your menu, if you needed to expose the CPT to the `wp_nav_menu()` CSS.