# Highlighting current item of custom post types' sub pages, listed by wp_list_pages

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, wp-list-pages

The below code is for listing the custom post types itself and its children in the sidebar.
The code works great but does not highlight the sub pages.

In `functions.php`:

```
if(!function_exists('get_post_top_ancestor_id')){
/**
* Gets the id of the topmost ancestor of the current page. Returns the current
* page's id if there is no parent.
* 
* @uses object $post
* @return int 
*/
function get_post_top_ancestor_id(){
global $post;

if($post->post_parent){
    $ancestors = array_reverse(get_post_ancestors($post->ID));
    return $ancestors[0];
}

return $post->ID;
}}
```

and adding this code to the sidebar:

```
<ul>
<?php
$getid=get_post_top_ancestor_id(); 
#echo $getid;
global $post;
$post=get_post($getid);
setup_postdata($post);
?>
<?php
if (is_single($post->ID)) {$pg_li .="current_page_item";}
else {
$pg_li .="page_item";}
?>
<h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
<p></p>
<li class="<?php echo $pg_li; ?>">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">BIOGRAPHY</a>
</li>
<li class="<?php echo $pg_li; ?>">
<?php
$args=array(
'post_type'=>'artists',
'child_of'=>$getid ,
'sort_column'=>'menu_order',
'hierarchical' => 1,
'title_li'=>__('')
);
wp_list_pages( $args );
wp_reset_query();
?></li>
</ul>
```

I am not familiar with PHP, and a friend helped me to write this code. So what am I missing to highlight the current sub menu of that custom post type?

Comment: Do you actually have a unique style in your css for `.current_page_item`?

Comment: @JohannesPille yes, i have..

Comment: Would it be possible to list them with a custom navigation menu instead of the code you used? Reason I ask is because if you can replace it with a custom navigation menu you can use: http://vayu.dk/highlighting-wp_nav_menu-ancestor-children-custom-post-types/

Comment: Can we see the rendered page?

Comment: There is a hack on the link: http://www.mark-leong.com/wordpress-hack-force-wp_list_pages-to-print-current_page_item-class/,  Or checkout this one http://kucrut.org/wp_list_pages-for-custom-post-types/

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this code is that the query is being altered and `current_page_item` is being lost. This is the part causing problems.

```
$post = get_post( $getid );
setup_postdata( $post );
```

If you comment out those two lines you'll see that `current_page_item` appears.

There are also some secondary problems with this code that have no bearing on the main problem.

1. `<p></p>` should not exist as a child element of `<ul>`. Only `<li>` is allowed.
2. `<h3>...</h3>` also should not exist as a child element of `<ul>` for the same reasons as #1.
3. The `if` statement setting the CSS class for the "Biography" link will return true on *any* single page, not just the parent page.
4. `wp_list_pages()` outputs a list of `<li>...</li>` tag pairs so it doesn't need to be wrapped with another pair of `<li>...</li>` tags.

The following code corrects all the issues.

```
<?php
$getid = get_post_top_ancestor_id(); 
global $post;
?>
<h3><?php echo get_the_title( $getid );?></h3>
<ul>
    <?php
    if ( $post->ID == $getid ) {
        $pg_li .= "current_page_item";
    } else {
        $pg_li .= "page_item";
    }
    ?>  
    <li class="<?php echo $pg_li; ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $getid ); ?>">BIOGRAPHY</a>
    </li>
    <?php
    $args=array(
        'post_type' => 'artists',
        'child_of' => $getid,
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'title_li' => __('')
    );
    wp_list_pages( $args );
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a fix coming up for the same, here is the ticket: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/27755

In case you need it urgently, you can give this a try

Original Answer by @goldenapples, here is the link:

[Dynamic navigation for custom post type (pages)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3247/dynamic-navigation-for-custom-post-type-pages/3270#3270)

```
function wp_list_post_types( $args ) {
$defaults = array(
    'numberposts'  => -1,
    'offset'       => 0,
    'orderby'      => 'menu_order, post_title',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'post_type'    => 'page',
    'depth'        => 0,
    'show_date'    => '',
    'date_format'  => get_option('date_format'),
    'child_of'     => 0,
    'exclude'      => '',
        'include'      => '',
    'title_li'     => __('Pages'),
    'echo'         => 1,
    'link_before'  => '',
    'link_after'   => '',
    'exclude_tree' => '' );

$r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
extract( $r, EXTR_SKIP );

$output = '';
$current_page = 0;

// sanitize, mostly to keep spaces out
$r['exclude'] = preg_replace('/[^0-9,]/', '', $r['exclude']);

// Allow plugins to filter an array of excluded pages (but don't put a nullstring into the array)
$exclude_array = ( $r['exclude'] ) ? explode(',', $r['exclude']) : array();
$r['exclude'] = implode( ',', apply_filters('wp_list_post_types_excludes', $exclude_array) );

// Query pages.
$r['hierarchical'] = 0;
$pages = get_posts($r);

if ( !empty($pages) ) {
    if ( $r['title_li'] )
        $output .= '<li class="pagenav">' . $r['title_li'] . '<ul>';

    global $wp_query;
    if ( ($r['post_type'] == get_query_var('post_type')) || is_attachment() )
        $current_page = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
    $output .= walk_page_tree($pages, $r['depth'], $current_page, $r);

    if ( $r['title_li'] )
        $output .= '</ul></li>';
}

$output = apply_filters('wp_list_pages', $output, $r);

if ( $r['echo'] )
    echo $output;
else
    return $output;
 }
```