# current-menu-item not working with custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, navigation

I'm a wordpress newbie and I have annoying problem. I have a few custom post types (capability_type=post). Two of them i created with "Custom Post Types" plugin and when i put its categories in navigation menu they are working well. When clicked it gets current-menu-item. The problem is with one of the other post type (Events) which is created by "Events Manager" plugin. When its categories are included in navigation menu, and clicked they don't get class current-menu-item ... there is nothing starting with current in classes. Can anyone help me pleace?
Link to the site:
http://ideas4web.eu/sedmicata.com/

Look at the big red navigation and Events li and its sub-menu.
I've read [This post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3247/dynamic-navigation-for-custom-post-type-pages/3270#3270) but i can't figure it out how to make it work.

Print screen in admin area [here](http://ideas4web.eu/sedmicata.com/admin_area_nav.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! Please try [our search](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=current-menu-item%20%5Bcustom-post-types%5D). Add your research efforts to your question.

Comment: I have replicated this issue on a WordPress installation using the TwentyTwelve theme so this appears to be an issue with the plugin. There is a [support thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/highlight-current-events-page-on-main-menu) where the plugin author may be able to provide a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved!**
The problem was in the plugins settings ...
To fix this problem go to:
**Events**(Left Admin Sidebar) -> **Settings** -> **Pages** -> **Event Categories**
and set "**Override with Formats?**" to **NO**
Thats it ... I hope this information to be useful for others, and save them a lot of time, which they coud use for a walk, drinking beer and whatever they want. ;)
Cheers!